# Qual a maneira mais eficiente de se matar um processo externo a partir de um programa escrito em C?

Tags: c, processo

**A minha versão:**

```
//test.c (04/07/2019)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void stop_attack(pid_t child){

    int wstatus;

    system("killall xerxes");

    if(kill(child, SIGTERM)!=0){

        kill(child, SIGKILL);
    }

    wait(&wstatus);
}

int main(void){

    const time_t timer=3600;

    pid_t child=fork();

    if(child<0){

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }else if(child==0){

        for(time_t i=0; i<=timer; i++){

            usleep(1000000);
        }

        __kill(child);

    }else{

        system("./xerxes 127.0.0.1 80");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[xerxes.c](https://github.com/zanyarjamal/xerxes/blob/master/xerxes.c)

No caso acima eu utilizei uma chamada do sistema (`system("killall xerxes")`), porém não tenho certeza se essa é uma abordagem eficiente e segura, pois podem ocorrer situações onde isso pode falhar.

Existe uma maneira mais eficiente e segura de se matar um processo externo via programa escrito em **C**, sem que haja a necessidade de uso da função `system()`?

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você está em um sistema operacional da família do UNIX, a função `kill()` da biblioteca de sistema `signal.h`, pode resolver o seu problema.

Porém, a função `kill()` só é capaz de enviar sinais para um processo a partir do seu `PID`, ou seja, você vai precisar **descobrir** o identificador (ou os identificadores) do processo que você quer "matar". Lembrando que um mesmo executável pode possuir várias instâncias (cópias) em execução, cada uma com um `PID` único.

Em sistemas `UNIX`, o diretório `/proc` é responsável por armazenar a relação dos `PIDs` com os executáveis que estão rodando no sistema.

Segue um código (testado) capaz de resolver o problema sem o uso da função `system()`, veja só:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    const char * procdir = "/proc";
    size_t namelen = PATH_MAX;
    char * name = NULL;
    DIR * dir = NULL;
    struct dirent * de = NULL;
    int pid = -1;
    char cmdline_file[PATH_MAX+1] = {0};
    FILE * cmdline = NULL;
    int ret = 0;

    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Sintaxe: %s <NOME_DO_PROCESSO>\n", argv[0] );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    name = calloc( 1, namelen );

    if(!name)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "calloc(): memoria insuficiente\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    dir = opendir("/proc");

    if(!dir)
    {
        perror("opendir()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while((de = readdir(dir)) != 0)
    {
        if( !strcmp(de->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(de->d_name, "..") )
            continue;

        ret = sscanf(de->d_name, "%d", &pid);

        if( ret == 1 )
        {
            sprintf( cmdline_file, "%s/%d/cmdline", procdir, pid );

            cmdline = fopen(cmdline_file, "r");

            if(!cmdline)
                continue;

            if(getline(&name, &namelen, cmdline))
            {
                if(strstr( name, argv[1] ))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Enviando SIGKILL para processo de PID: %d...", pid );

                    ret = kill( pid, SIGKILL );

                    if( ret < 0 )
                        fprintf(stderr,"Falhou!\n");
                    else
                        fprintf(stderr,"OK\n");
                }
            }

            fclose(cmdline);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
    free(name);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```